# how can I get a end of word from this line

Tags: bash, grep

I tried this.

```
'svn info | grep revision'
```

so I can get

```
Revision: 36991
```

but the word I want is only

> 36991

how can I do this?  maybe with '`grep`'

or `shell script`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work for you -

```
svn info | awk '/Revision/{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed, the stream editor (or awk or cut).

```
svn info | grep revision | sed "s/[^0-9]\+//"

svn info | sed -e '/revision/!d' -e 's/[^0-9]\+//'

svn info | awk '/revision/ { print $2 }'

svn info | grep revision | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Comment: This won't work. You forgot to add `+` to make it `greedy` plus you don't really need `grep`. May be something like this `svn info | sed '/Revision/s/[^0-9]\+//'`

Comment: Cool .. You probably need to escape it or use `sed -r`.

Comment: LOL.  Confirmed.  I'll fix it...  Again.  Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
svn info | sed -n 's/^Revision: //p'
```